# Получения изображения из Яндекс диска

Tags: php, opencart, яндекс-диск

Я создаю электронный каталог товаров на системе opencart. Картинок очень много, поэтому я загрузил все в каталог на яндекс диск. Теперь нужно на сайте вывести картинки продуктов прямо из яндекс диска. Я загружаю товары из .xls файла. В файле ссылка на картинку выглядит так:

```
image/product1.jpg
```

в opencart я изменил  `/catalog/model/tool/image.php` четвёртую строку так:

```
if (!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename) || !is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
return HTTP_IMAGE.$filename;
}
```

HTTP_IMAGE объявлено в config.php и admin/config.php:

```
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'https://yadi.sk/d/LgdasdGasdfLC/');
```

HTTP_IMAGE.$filename возвращает:

```
https://yadi.sk/d/LgdasdGasdfLC/image/product1.jpg
```

но картинка на сайте не открывается. Как мне правильно загрузить картинки прямо из яндекс диска?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использую [этот](https://github.com/jack-theripper/yandex) SDK для PHP, там работает вот такой кусок для получения изображения:

```
$resource = $disk->getResource(DIR_IMAGE . $filename);
$link = $resource->getLink();
```

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему никак. Картинки из кэша берутся, а туда они из оригинала изображения под разные размеры конвертируются. На сайт выводится не оригинал image.jpg, а измененное изображение image-150x150, например.